# Iterate through an an array in PHP without using count and sizeof function

Tags: php, arrays

My task is to create a function named 'maximum' that will find the max in a given set of numbers. My function should return the max number.

Requirement:

My function should not use 'sizeof' or 'count' function that counts the number of elements in the array.
How will I do that? This is my PHP function:

```
function maximum($array){

    $elements = count($array);
    $max = $array[0];
    for($a=1; $a < $elements; $a++){
        if ($max < $array[$a]){
            $max =  $array[$a];
        }
    }

    return $max;
}
```

Comment: ever head of `foreach`?

Comment: you dont want to use function `max()` too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using built-in function:

```
$max = max($array);
```

Using foreach:

```
$max = 0;
foreach ( $array as $item ) {
    if ( $max<$item ) {
        $max = $item;
    }
}
```

Using sorting function:

```
rsort($array);
$max = array_shift($array);
```

or

```
sort($array);
$max = array_pop($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$max = $array[0];
foreach ($array as $value) {
    if ($max < $value){
        $max =  $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function maximum($array) {
  $max = 0;
  foreach($array as $value) { // get every value of array
    if($max < $value) // if value of array is bigger then last one
      $max = $value; // put it into $max
  }
  return $max;
}
```

Comment: please put some explanation to your code posted, this will help others to understand quickly.

Answer (score 0):

you could do this by [max()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php)

```
echo max($array);
```